# No output to iframe after using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using window.location.href in a php function which forces a file download without opening an additional window. The file download works and the rest of the php script executes. However, nothing that I output after the line with the javascript in the function will show up in the iframe. Is there a way to redirect the output back to the original php script?

Here is the javascript line from the php file:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='download.php';</script>";
```

Here is the code from download.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starts new or resumes existing session
$filename = $_SESSION['filename']; // Creates variable from session variable
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // Output text file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); // Output file name
readfile($filename); // Outputs the text file
?>
```

This is an example of something in the php file that will not output to the iframe after the line of javascript:

```
echo 'Test Output';
```

Thanks in advance,

Jay

EDIT

I replaced the line of javascript with the following and it works perfectly:

```
echo "<iframe id='my_iframe' style='display:none;' src='download.php'></iframe>";
```

Comment: If you redirected the page, then it will show what the new page shows not the old one. Put your echo in the download file php script and it should show.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That makes sense. Is there a way to redirect back to the php file that was already running?

Comment: Not practical. And that way you wouldn't be actually using an iframe for download. More like one page. Check answer for better approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the redirect inside the iframe page.

The best way I can think of atm is to use an invisible frame as mentioned in Andrew Dunn's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Quoting from that answer:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download(url) {
document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
};
</script>
```

Have that inside your main page. url is basically the download url ("download.php" in your case). You can use a button to make the download manual. If you want it forced. Add src=url to the iframe and remove the script.

I would advice researching and using jQuery.

Comment: Awesome, I replaced the javascript line with: `echo "<iframe style='display:none;' src='download.php'></iframe>";` and the script now downloads the file and outputs as intended. Thank you for your help.